# Hazelcast Embedded Mode

Tags: hazelcast

Hazelcast Deployment and Operations Guide states

> If your application requires very low latency, consider using an
>   embedded deployment. This configuration will deliver the best latency
>   characteristics.

Is there any recommended cluster size for embedded operations  to achieve low latency?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a cut and dry question.  A single node cluster gives you the lowest latency because all your data will reside in your single vm along with your application because you don't incur any additional costs in serialization and chattiness.  Obviously, this defeats the purpose of Hazelcast which provides for you the features required for the CAP Theorem like High Availability.  That aside, you simply may not fit all your data in a single node.  From here, as you add more nodes, that latency may increase if your embedded app is accessing data from another node, especially if it has multiple round-trips.  But, you will more likely increase throughput, thus the ability to process more concurrently, because you'll have more cpu and memory available across all your nodes.

Sizing your cluster will depend on the usual variables such as: available heap size, data (object) size, count, indexes, retention policy, and estimated growth.  There are many other variables to be considered that will affect the size of your cluster.

Comment: Thanks @Manny David.The support site states Client-server topology is a better fit when there are multiple applications sharing the same data or if the application deployment is significantly greater than the required Hazelcast cluster size.What is the "required Hazelcast cluster size"?

Comment: In this context, if the number of application servers, let's say you can only have 2 web-servers (hosting your application[s]), but, as noted in ops guide on how to size your cluster, requires 3+ nodes, then, client-server, is your option.

Comment: Hazelcast also speaks about embedded mode while scaling microservices incase of Kubernetes.Does that mean those microservices cannot scale beyond two nodes?
https://hazelcast.com/blog/how-to-use-embedded-hazelcast-on-kubernetes/

States
"Hazelcast IMDG is a perfect fit for your (micro)services running on Kubernetes since it can be used in the embedded mode and therefore scale in and out together with your service replicas"

Comment: Kindly sight the section of Ops Guide which states so , I have the guide for latest version of Hazelcast 3.12

Comment: The blog you cited has a url which answers your question about number of nodes:  https://hazelcast.com/blog/how-to-scale-hazelcast-imdg-on-kubernetes.  As for the ops guide, it talks about advantages of Embedded vs Client-Server in detail, please have a read.

Answer (score 1):

Embedded mode provides 1/N of data localisation where N is the number of servers in the cluster and data locality gets smaller with increase in cluster size. Apart from that, there is no real performance benefit with Embedded mode.

With Client-Server, although all data is remote but servers operate in their dedicate environment i.e. not sharing JVM and other resources with application code. This also means you will not be forced to run an application instance in order to run Hazelcast server, which btw is the case with embedded mode.

On a side note: if low latency is the requirement then NearCache can be used in either of the deployment modes.

Determining cluster size depends on various factors: size of total data to be cached, backup count, required TPS and Latency, need Index for queries etc. The guide covers those aspects in detail.